# How to search a full name in sql server database table with only firstname and lastname column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, azure-sql-database

We have a DB table, User with `first_name`, `last_name` columns but do not have a `full_name` column. We want to perform a search on the table, where the search query can contain the string which is a combination of both columns or one of them or simply a character. Search has to case insensitive.

Edit 1
The search needs to be fast enough as the request would be from a typeahead on a webclient.

Comment: Add a (persisted) computed column and query that? We don't have a lot to go on here.

Comment: Why not search both columns? Do you need to scan anywhere in the fields or just at the start? Only *prefix* searches (ie `LIKE 'abc%'`) can take advantage of indexing. If you want fast performance you'll have to enable and use [Full Text Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/full-text-search?view=sql-server-2017) indexing

Comment: `the request would be from a typeahead on a webclient.` does this means you only need a *prefix* search? `WHERE First_Name like @text + '%' OR Last_Name like @text + '%'`. If you index `First_Name` and `Last_Name` separately, the query becomes a *range* seek on the two indexes

Comment: `Search has to case insensitive.` that depends on the collation you've used in the table. The most common collations are case-insensitive. You can check whether a collation is case or accent sensitive from its name. CI means Case Insensitive

Comment: Hi Hemant, did the answer worked for you?

Answer (score 1):

The `LIKE` expressions by default are case insensitive. As @larnu suggested, adding a persistent column is a better way of going about it. And if you can do a prefix search on that, it will further speed things up. If those are not an option, try this to see if you can tolerate the performance:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS (" ", first_name, last_name) full_name
FROM YourTable
WHERE CONCAT_WS (" ", first_name, last_name) LIKE '%some string%';
```

Comment: This will force a full table scan

Answer (score 0):

A db table and an example would be easier to work with, but the simple case, should be something like the query below
I would make sure the search string is converted to lower case.
Notice that such a query on a large scale database might not be that quick

```
SELECT
*
FROM
users u
WHERE
 LOWER(CONCAT(u.first_name,u.last_name)) LIKE '%{@search_string_here}%'
```

Comment: `LOWER` isn't needed unless the collation is case-sensitive. `LIKE '%..%'` will have to perform a full table scan anyway, as it can't use any indexes. `CONCAT` will cause the same problem too. Finally The LIKE operation here *doesn't* search for any parameters, just a string that contains `{@....}`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking at the format of your search term being the same with a `firstname[space]lastname` combination, you could do something like the below:

```
SELECT *
FROM Names
WHERE LEFT([Firstname] + ' ' + [lastname], LEN(@searchname)) = @searchname
```

This would allow you to search by the length of your search name. An example of how this could work is below:

```
CREATE TABLE Names
(
    firstname NVARCHAR(100),
    lastname NVARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT INTO Names VALUES
('John', 'Smith'), ('Jane', 'Doe'), ('Harry', 'Potter')


DECLARE @searchname NVARCHAR(100)

--John (Fist Name match only)
SET @searchname = 'John'
SELECT *
FROM Names
WHERE LEFT([Firstname] + ' ' + [lastname], LEN(@searchname)) = @searchname

--Jane D (First name + Initial Last name)
SET @searchname = 'Jane D'
SELECT *
FROM Names
WHERE LEFT([Firstname] + ' ' + [lastname], LEN(@searchname)) = @searchname


--H (Single character only in correct order)
SET @searchname = 'H'
SELECT *
FROM Names
WHERE LEFT([Firstname] + ' ' + [lastname], LEN(@searchname)) = @searchname
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query:

```
SELECT first_name,last_name,  CONCAT(CONCAT(first_name,' '),last_name)  full_name  
FROM User_table WHERE CONCAT(CONCAT(first_name,' '),last_name) LIKE '%string%'
```

Or:

```
SELECT first_name,last_name,  CONCAT(first_name,last_name)  full_name  
FROM User_table WHERE CONCAT(fistName,lastName) LIKE '%string%'
```

For example, I create a table like you, and run this query get the result you want.

TB3:

[image]

Restult1:

[image]

Restult2:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: This will result in a full table scan as it can't take advantage of any indexes for two reasons - `CONCAT` creates a value that doesn't exist in any index and `LIKE '%leon%'` searches in the entire index, something that can't use normal indexes